# Firebase Authentification Login not possible

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Trying to read Firebase document I got following error:

D/DocSnippets: Error getting documents: 
    com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I use following firebase Auth rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

LogIn via e.g. Facebook seems working:

[image]

Can someone help me why I can not receive data from firebase? If I Change Auth rules in firebase to no authentification everything works fine.

Comment: Can you show the exact request that you're making?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that you are using to read the "documents".  Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Using following auth rules everything is working fine:rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }